# PostgreSQL regular expression with LIKE or similarto

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out the pattern match with postgresql LIKE operator to perform a search for particular pattern.

For example,

```
select usename  
FROM tablename 
where CAST(usename AS VARCHAR) LIKE  'abc__________'
```

What my table contains:

```
abc_akdufhdhlu
abc_edf_kliokkklos
edf_poiuyterdh
abc_lkjhgfgaha
abc_hhh_kaolloiaeh
abc_oasdhehwjwo
```

What I am getting

```
abc_akdufhdhlu
abc_lkjhgfgaha
abc_oasdhehwjwo
```

I want to achieve same thing without using `abc__________`.

Is there better way writing pattern matching in Postgres that match pattern: fixedString(`abc_`) followed by 10 random characters `[a-zA-Z]`.
ex: `abc_[a-zA-z]`

Comment: The `cast` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query if you want to get abc with any suffix

```
select usename  FROM tablename where CAST(usename AS VARCHAR) LIKE  'abc_' || '%'
```

If you want to do that two way(prefix and suffix)

```
select usename  FROM tablename where CAST(usename AS VARCHAR) LIKE  '%'||'abc_' || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the regex operator `~`

```
select usename
from tablename
where usename ~ '^abc_[a-zA-Z]{10}$`
```

The `^` and `$` are there to ensure the whole value is matched.

Alternatively you can use `similar to`

```
select usename
from tablename
where usename similar to 'abc_[a-zA-Z]{10}'
```

`similar to` always matches the whole string, so the `^` and `$` are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  both are working for me. Will go with `similar to`